# How to change the credentials that get used when using CRM for outlook?

Tags: networking, plugins, outlook, connection, crm

I am trying to use the CRM for outlook plugin from outside our domain. Using CRM online is not an option. The web application is accessible from outside the network - using an https binding. When I am inside the network, I put this address as the Server URL, and it works fine. When I'm outside I get these errors: 
Exception : SOAP security negotiation with '' for target '' failed -
AND:
The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed

So my guess would be it is trying to log on - getting my windows authentication - and not working because the domain is not correct. How do i change this?

If my guess is completely off base then please point me in the right direction. If anyone has dealt with a similar problem to this then please help. I have been researching this for the past few days and have yet to come up with a solution. Thanks for your help!